# kind: YARN_CLIENT_TOKEN, User class threw exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/username/config.properties (No such file or directory)

Tags: apache-spark, command-line-arguments, hadoop-yarn, filenotfoundexception, file-not-found

I am trying to run the below spark-submit command reading config file from command line args, when I run the code on local it runs fine, but when I run using yarn, it fails with the below error

**Spark Submit :**

> time spark-submit --files /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --class IntegrateAD /home/username/s3ReadWrite-assembly-1.1.jar "day0" "/home/username/config.properties"

**Error :**

> INFO yarn.Client:
> client token: Token { kind: YARN_CLIENT_TOKEN, service:  }
> diagnostics: User class threw exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/username/config.properties (No such file or directory)
> at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
> at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
> at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)

**Code I am running :**

```
val propFile = new File(args(1))
val properties: Properties = new Properties()

if (propFile != null) {
  // val source = Source.fromFile(propFile)
  //properties.load(source.bufferedReader())
  properties.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))
  properties
}
else {
  logger.error("properties file cannot be loaded at path " + propFile)
  throw new FileNotFoundException("Properties file cannot be loaded")
}
```

Please help me with what maybe wrong here, in my code or my spark-submit or is it something else.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: There is something wrong with your file path name("/home/username/config.properties"). File Input Stream cannot find the file. What you can do is go to the config file in the /home/username directory and right click the file and go to file properties. From there you can get the root path of the file. Use that file path as the argument in your spark submit command. Thanks

Comment: Hi Nihad, Thanks for the response, but the file is on the cluster , not in my local.

Comment: By cluster, do you mean inside your Master Node where you are currently running your spark-submit script?

Comment: Yes, @NihadTP . It is where my driver program runs